# Fixing CWE ID 117 in Rabbitmq client Library

Tags: rabbitmq, veracode

My software uses RabbitMQ for communication. However, Veracode has flagged CWE 117 (Improper output neutralization for logs) from the amqp-client library.

[image]

I have tried to upgrade to the latest version (4.11.3), but Veracode still does not let me pass. I cannot upgrade further as my software are written in Java 7, and the client do not have any plans to upgrade to Java 8.

Is there any things I can do in my software code to get rid of CWE 117 issue?

Comment: For the record: [line 110](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client/blob/99213bdf6ba4eeaa5ce0ad3707e01541ee4acdf7/src/main/java/com/rabbitmq/client/impl/TlsUtils.java#L110)

Comment: I've opened an issue: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client/issues/622

Comment: Please check if the JAR linked in https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client/issues/622#issuecomment-520332355 sattisfies Veracode.

Comment: @LutzHorn, thank for your support. As Veracode is owned by my client, I need to discuss with my client on verification.

Comment: Please add your comments to the GitHub issue I've linked above. This will prevent the discussion from happening at two places.

Answer (score 1):

The lines in question log peer certificate chain information when peer verification fails, at `DEBUG` level. I don't think it poses any practical risk as most applications do not run with debug logging enabled. In any case, mitigation is as easy as using a more restrictive log level, e.g. `INFO`.